# Cross domain for maintaining browser session using CURL

Tags: php, session, browser, curl

I am making a CURL get request via php to another domain to get json value, but as i know curl uses temporary session, but how can i maintain all the browser session in curl request ? here is my code

```
    // create curl resource 
    $ch = curl_init(); 

    // set url 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://api.json");  //api.json is displaying value from session 

    //return the transfer as a string 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);

    // $output contains the output string 
    $output = curl_exec($ch); 

    // close curl resource to free up system resources 
    curl_close($ch);
```

how can i maintain the browser session ...

Comment: What do you mean by browser session? The session used when calling this script?

Comment: yeah as in when i am calling a json request it should have the session which i am currently in ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);            
        $cookie_value = $cookie_name.'='.$_SESSION[$cookie_name];
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie_value);            
        $xml_contents = curl_exec ($ch);
        curl_close ($ch);
        return $xml_contents;
```

For this you need to store the cookie and in next request attach into the header that works .

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` option (see [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)) to save all cookies to a file. You can import this file at a later time using the `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` option, this will send all cookies stored in the specified jar.

Example based on your code for keeping a persistent session between script executions:

```
// create curl resource 
$ch = curl_init(); 

// set url 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://api.json");  //api.json is displaying value from session 

//return the transfer as a string 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

// Set the cookie jar for both importing and exporting
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "curl-cookie-session.tmp");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "curl-cookie-session.tmp");

// $output contains the output string 
$output = curl_exec($ch); 

// close curl resource to free up system resources 
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: but will it save only for the current browser ??

Comment: @user1245078 I'm not sure what you mean, are your worried to cookies won't be reusable for other visitors? If you store the cookies in a jar, you can reuse them even in different executions of the script.

Comment: @user1245078 I've updated my answer with an example for your situation. Create the (empty) cookie jar file beforehand, and if you'd like to clear all cookies at some point just purge the file. If you want to maintain a different cookie sessions for every user of your script, you'll have to use a seperate cookie jar file for every user.

Comment: Thanks for the code but its still giving the error as the sessions are not maintained ...

Comment: @user1245078 Are you perhaps still using `CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION`? This option should be set to **`false`** for this system to work.

Comment: @user1245078 I've verified that the code does work for persisting cookies between sessions. Could you create a reproducible test case in which it doesn't work for you?

Comment: Ok so here is my problem... i have to call two api request .. 1st request would store items in his session and in the second request i am calling to view that stored items in the session. so in that case the above code is not working ...

Comment: @KetanMujumdar Please add all relevant code of that case to your question. It's hard to see what's wrong without any code.